# C++ threading - no matching function for call to

Tags: c++, multithreading, syntax-error

This is my first time using threads in c++ and I have some issues with it. I am getting error

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<packetInfo> >::value_type*)’
```

This is my code excerpt:

```
std::vector<packetInfo> sentPackets; // global var

void renewIP(struct packetInfo *currentPacket) {
...//code
}

void anotherFuntion() {

    ...
    std::thread renewTimer(renewIP, &(sentPackets[i]));
    renewTimer.detach();
    ...
}
```

I have absolutely no idea what am I doing wrong or why am I getting the error.

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't tried to compile this code, but it obviously has a bunch more problems than the one that the question describes. Post real code.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ffa37d5122e1345).

Comment: I tried derefrencing the function name but m getting the same error. And I am compiling it as -std=c++11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error tells you directly:

```
<unresolved overloaded function type>
```

You must have multiple overloads of `renewIP`, and the compiler doesn't know which one you want.  You can either rename them to make them not ambiguous, or make it explicit via a cast:

```
std::thread renewTimer((void(*)(struct packetInfo*))renewIP, &(sentPackets[i]));
```

Comment: Damn you're right. I changed the function parameter and forgot to also change it in header file. Sorry for the dumb question.